# Ubuntu 14.04 - Network card not showing up

Tags: networking, 14.04

My network card isn't showing up when I run `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`, but it shows up when I run

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Comment: Please edit your post to tell us what lspci -nn | grep 0280 says.

Comment: What's the output you are getting from that command? We need to know the model of your network card to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` shows the configuration of the network interfaces. iwconfig does the same for wireless interfaces. `lspci` shows information about hardware connected to the PCI bus. It seems they are all doing their job. For more info do:

```
man ifconfig
man lspci
```

etc.